# Find intermediary extension

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $P$ be the polynomial

$$
P=64X^9 + 192X^7 + 240X^6 + 36X^5 + 552X^4 - 847X^3 - 540X^2 + 273X + 143
$$

Then $P$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, and has three real roots. Let $\alpha$ be one of those real roots. I would like to know if there is an intermediary extension $\mathbb K$ lying strictly between ${\mathbb Q}$ and ${\mathbb Q}(\alpha)$ (which forces $[{\mathbb K}:{\mathbb Q}]=3$), and compute a minimal polynomial of a primitive element of $\mathbb K$ if possible.

How difficult is this problem ?

Comment: In Sage they've yet to implement number fields for non-monic polynomials/non-integral coefficients. I'm not sure if Magma would be able to help with the computation.

Comment: @Jacob, if you replace $x$ by $x/2$, and then multiply through by $8$, you don't change the field, and you get a monic polynomial. Would Sage be able to handle it then?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, Sage seems to be able to cope now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Gerry Myerson's suggestion I did the appropriate transformation of the polynomial and ran the following code in Sage.

```
sage: p=QQ[x](x^9 + 12*x^7 + 30*x^6 + 9*x^5 + 276*x^4 - 847*x^3 - 1080*x^2 + 1092*x + 1144)
sage: L=NumberField(p,'z')
sage: L.subfields(3)
[]
```

So Sage seems to think there are no subfields of degree $3$.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, Maple can do it directly.

```
> P:= 64*X^9+192*X^7+240*X^6+36*X^5+552*X^4-847*X^3-540*X^2+273*X+143:
> evala(Subfields(P, 3));
```

$$ \{\ \} $$