# is the set difference ℝ \ R still uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know that the set of real numbers are uncountable by cantors diagonal argument.
But the set difference of ℝ and R (Real numbers minus itself) must equal an empty set right? And an empty set is itself countable? Or is it a trick question where they are only defining R as a subset (not all) of real numbers?

**Question:** Consider the set R of real numbers which can be written in one of the usual ways: strings of digits with an optional negative sign and/or an optional  decimal point, a fraction sign between such strings, and/or such strings with square root signs.

- Is this set R finite; infinite but countable; or not countable? Explain your answer
- Is ℝ \ R countable or uncountable?

Comment: Any significance to the two different typefaces for the letter R?

Comment: Yes. That is what is so strange. The question has two different typefaces. So Im not sure if R is referring to ℝ and whether they are the same or not

Comment: You have defined $R$ as a subset of $\Bbb R$: it is "the set of real numbers which can be written in one of the usual ways: [etc.]" It does not necessarily refer to the set of real numbers. If it turns out that $R = \Bbb R$ (which remains for you to determine), then you're right that of course the set difference would be empty, hence trivially countable.

Comment: @Théophile assuming that they are both the same. Is ℝ \ ℝ uncountable or countable?

Comment: I think what the question means by a strings of digits is, it consists of a finite amount of digits. Or else the rest of the definition doesn't make sense.

Comment: @nugh The empty set is very much countable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that $\mathbb{R} \setminus R$ is uncountably infinite. The set $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$, and is contained inside the set of real algebraic numbers. But the set of real algebraic numbers is countably infinite. Hence,

1. $R$ is countably infinite.
2. $\mathbb{R} \setminus R$ is uncountably infinite.

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/292330/577979) for more details.

Comment: I think it's a typo : the set of algebraic real numbers is not finite... But it is countable

Comment: @DIdier_ oops, I meant to say countably infinite, I have edited. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Given two finite strings of digits we can only make $m$ many representations such as a sloppily described: e..g from 123 and 456 I can make 1.23 / 45.6 or -12.3 , or $-\sqrt{123}$ etc. I don't care what $m$ is as long as it is finite. Then observe there are actually only countably many strings (which I consider to be of finite length!) of digits, and so only countably many pairs of strings of digits. All such pair only beget finitely many representations so $R$ is at amost countable, and $\Bbb R \setminus R$ in fact has the same size as $\Bbb R$ (in particular uncountable).